# Listen to the end of widget initializations done by the Dojo parser

Tags: javascript, dojo, single-page-application

I am developing a single-page web-application with Dojo 1.9.

We use the Dojo Parser to initialize widgets in HTML fragments loaded from the server into a dojox.layout.ContentPane.

Before we insert the ContentPane into the page, we want to wait until all of the widgets finish initialization completely.

Is there a way to do this?

I have been trying to achieve this by waiting on the promise returned by ContentPane.content but this seems to get resolved earlier.

```
var onParseEnd = pane.set("content", htmlText);
```

I think that onParseEnd gets resolved immediately after the parser has "parsed" the HTML content and not after all of the widget initializations have finished.

Comment: have you tried dojo/parser?. It returns a promise which gets resolved after all the dojo widgets gets instantiated. e.g  `require (["dojo/parser"], function ( parser ){ parser.parse( html_fragment ).then(onComplete_Callback);});`

Comment: Unfortunatelly, we only use dojo/parser indirectly. We call 'ContentPane.set("content", htmlFragment)' because that also executes the Javascript placed into the fragment, attaches CSS...etc

Comment: As per the dojox/contentpane [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/layout/ContentPane.html#id6) at the **end** it does offer a clue ( unfortunately it is not clear) which might be a solution to your problem. The documentation goes like this. 
    Through the use of the **scriptHasHooks** setting, a **Deferred instance**, **onLoadDeferred** and it’s then() method, you can simulate the **dojo.ready** behavior from inside the loaded content.
    An alternative is to set scriptHasHooks=true, and have content like this in your loaded content:

Comment: Here is a discussion on dojo [forum](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/dijit-byId-not-working-for-widgets-loaded-from-tabcontainer-via-href-attribute-td3331947.html) which relates to a similar problem

Comment: I have read the discussion and did some experimenting with the onLoadDeferred facility of ContentPane. My page seems to be doing initializations even after onLoadDeferred is resolved in ContentPane. On top of the declarative widgets, I initialize extra widgets from JavaScript code (placed in the HTML fragment) and those initializations are the ones that finish after onLoadDeferred. Am I right to assume that onLoadDeferred doesn't wait for the end of JavaScript snippet  executions in the fragment?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  `onLoadDeferred` only waits for the content itself to load (in the case of setting `href` rather than `content`) and for `parse` to run (in case there were any new modules that needed to be required).  Resolution isn't delayed for the script execution enabled by `dojox/layout/ContentPane` (actually handled by `dojox/html/_base`).  It is ideally preferable to organize JavaScript into modules and templated widgets as necessary so that your code is well-organized and you don't end up at the mercy of loose scripts evaluated as part of mixed content.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be sure the widgets have rendered you could consider **domReady!** to get an event firing after the widgets have initialized *and* have been rendered: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/domReady.html

However, the **startup()** event of your widget(s) is usually the better option, to avoid "glitches" where content is added/modified after having been rendered by the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think domReady! is suitable here. Since I am processing an HTML fragment (this is an SPA and the main page was loaded long ago), domReady! fires immediately and will not wait until widget initializations are finished in the fragment. domReady! may work like you say when you load a simple Dojo page (or a main/first page of an SPA).

Comment: Sorry, missed the SPA part.